# DateAdd & DateDiff Together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query which is looking to select all records where;

- ActualMinutes is 5 Greater then or equal to ScheduledMinutes and
- ActualMinutes is 5 Less then or equal to ScheduledMinutes.

E.g. If ScheduledMinutes is 60, I want any ActualMinutes between 55 & 65 (inclusive).

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT top 10000
        DateDiff(MI, StartTime, EndTime) as ScheduledMinutes, 
        DateDiff(MI, SignIn, SignOut) as ActualMinutes,
        *
        FROM tblRosteredCare 
        WHERE SignIn != 'M' AND SignOut != 'M' 
    ) DT
WHERE DT.ActualMinutes <= DT.ScheduledMinutes
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract one from the other and do a comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT top 10000
        DateDiff(Minute, StartTime, EndTime) as ScheduledMinutes, 
        DateDiff(Minute, SignIn, SignOut) as ActualMinutes,
        *
        FROM tblRosteredCare 
        WHERE SignIn != 'M' AND SignOut != 'M' 
    ) DT
WHERE DT.ActualMinutes - DT.ScheduledMinutes between -5 and 5
```

Or be cute and use `ABS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT top 10000
        DateDiff(Minute, StartTime, EndTime) as ScheduledMinutes, 
        DateDiff(Minute, SignIn, SignOut) as ActualMinutes,
        *
        FROM tblRosteredCare 
        WHERE SignIn != 'M' AND SignOut != 'M' 
    ) DT
WHERE ABS(DT.ActualMinutes - DT.ScheduledMinutes) <= 5
```